# Camel Simple Expression inside JsonPath Language?

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

I am trying to use simple expression inside jsonpath . I tried using built in operators such as 'contains','starts with' inside jsonpath to do a comparison with a header value.

I have tried using the contains operator and that works, but the starts with operator fails

What works -

```
.jsonpath("$.configs[?(@.mask contains '${header.mask}')]")
```

what does not work

```
.jsonpath("$.configs[?(@.mask starts with '${header.mask}')]")
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hi Claus, I am using 2.22.2

Comment: Maybe its the space in the function name, you can try using a regexp function that can also match with a starts-with token. Mind that getting the reg exp pattern correct can also be tricky

Comment: Thanks for the reply Claus.. I already had a regex that was doing the trick.. but was just hoping that the 'starts with' works... is more readable ...anyways thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

starts with does not work..for what reason I dont know..but then using a regex as shown below works

```
.jsonpath("$.configs[?(@.mask =~ /^\\${header.fileMask}.*?/i)]")
```

Comment: Yeah I have logged a ticket to make the functions not use space: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13430